# Changing the width of Bootstrap popover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am designing a page using Bootstrap 3. I am trying to use a popover with `placement: right` on an input element. The new Bootstrap ensures that if you use `form-control` you basically have a full-width input element.

The HTML code looks something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" 
                         data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" 
                         data-content="My popover content.My popover content.My popover content.My popover content." />
    </div>
</div>
```

The popovers width is too low, in my opinion because their isn't any width left in the div.
I want the input form on the left side, and a wide popover on the right side.

Mostly, I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to override Bootstrap.

The attached JsFiddle. The second input option. Haven't used jsfiddle a lot so don't know, but try increasing the size of the output box to see results, on smaller screens wouldn't even see it.
http://jsfiddle.net/Rqx8T/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div class="row" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" 
                 data-content="My popover content.My popover content.My popover content.My popover content.">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
```

Basically i put the popover code in the row div, instead of the input div. Solved the problem.

Comment: did not work for me. I did expect it to work  :(  Odd

Answer (score 375):

## Increase width with CSS

You can use CSS to increase the width of your popover, like so:

```
/* The max width is dependant on the container (more info below) */
.popover{
    max-width: 100%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
}
```

If this doesn't work, you probably want the solution below and alter your `container` element. ([View the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xp1369g4/))

---

## Twitter bootstrap Container

If that doesn't work, you probably need to specify the container:

```
// Contain the popover within the body NOT the element it was called in.
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    container: 'body'
});
```

---

#### More Info

[image: Twitter Bootstrap popover increase width]

The popover is contained within the element that it is triggered in. In order to extend it "full width" - specify the container:

```
// Contain the popover within the body NOT the element it was called in.
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    container: 'body'
});
```

---

### JSFiddle

View the JSFiddle to try it out.

## [JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xp1369g4/](http://jsfiddle.net/xp1369g4/)

Comment: +1, but will/may not work if your popover is in a modal: see my answer below.

Comment: The answer above was TLDR for me but contained this genius snippet which solved both the width and the problem of capturing all popovers:
`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    container: 'body'
});`

Comment: I had to add `!important`

Comment: You can use the neater data attribute: `data-container="body"` on the element

Comment: @surfer190 Neater on a per-popover basis, but clutter if you want *every* popover to have `container: "body"`.

Comment: Please also notice the @popover-max-width variable. If you compile the bootstrap less code yourself then it's easy to override those.

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem. Spent quite some time searching for an answer and found my own solution:
Add following text to the head:

> ```
> <style type="text/css">
>     .popover{
>         max-width:600px;
>     }
> </style>
> ```

Comment: You may need to add !important in order to override the bootstrap default setting.

Answer (score 39):

I also needed a wider popover for a search text field. I came up with this Javascript solution (here in [Coffee](http://js2coffee.org)):

```
$(".product-search-trigger")
  .click(-> false) # cancel click on <a> tag
  .popover
    container: "body"
    html: true
    placement: "left"
    title: "<strong>Product search</strong> enter number or name"
  .on("show.bs.popover", -> $(this).data("bs.popover").tip().css(maxWidth: "600px"))
```

The workaround is in the last line. Before the popover is being displayed the max-width option is set to a custom value. You could also add a custom class to the tip element.

Comment: If you're not Coffee-literate here's the same last line as regular js: `.on("show.bs.popover", function(){
    $(this).data("bs.popover").tip().css("max-width", "600px");
});`

Comment: What is .tip()? Why use .data()? XD I don't really understand this, but it work! I like this solution better than writing new CSS to replace the default `max-width`. Thank you for this solution!
Btw instead of `"600px"`, I set it to `"none"`. It's better for me.

Answer (score 29):

*To change width you can use css*

**For fixed size wanted**

```
.popover{
    width:200px;
    height:250px;    
}
```

**For max width wanted:**

```
.popover{
    max-width:200px;
    height:250px;    
}
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Rqx8T/2/

Comment: That would firstly change popover width across the site. But did find an answer.More correctly a workaround, posting it now.

Comment: @Peter, I can't reproduce your issue, I think you just forgot to add data-placement to your input...

Comment: @pbenard I am having same problem, your solution works for lowering the max-width than 276px. But if you will try to change max-width more than that than it won't change.

Answer (score 18):

To change the popover width you may override the template:

```
$('#name').popover({
    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip" style="width: 500px;"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><div class="data-content"></div></div></div>'
})
```

Comment: did not work for me.. I was required to add `max-width: 500px` to style too.

Answer (score 10):

For people who prefer the JavaScript solution.
In **Bootstrap 4** tip() became getTipElement() and it returns a no jQuery object. So in order to change the width of the popover in Bootstrap 4 you can use:

```
}).on("show.bs.popover", function() {
    $($(this).data("bs.popover").getTipElement()).css("max-width", "405px");
});
```

Comment: This has worked for me, however only when settings ```width``` not ```max-width```

Answer (score 8):

With the help of what @EML has described above regarding popover on modal windows and also the code shown by @2called-chaos, this is how I solved the problem.

I have an icon on the modal which when clicked should the popup

My HTML

```
<i title="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" rel="popover" data-title="Several Lines" data-content="A - First line<br />B - Second line - Long line <br />C - Third Line - Long Long Long Line"></i>
```

My Script

```
$('[rel=popover]').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: 'true',
    container: '#name-of-modal-window .modal-body'
}).on("show.bs.popover", function () { 
$(this).data("bs.popover").tip().css("max-width", "600px"); });
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's the non-coffeescript way of doing it with hover:

```
$(".product-search-trigger").popover({
    trigger: "hover",
    container: "body",
    html: true,
    placement: "left"
  }).on("show.bs.popover", function() {
    return $(this).data("bs.popover").tip().css({
      maxWidth: "300px"
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think "tip()" works - seems to be not a function (at least not in bootstrap 4), however "tip" does work, but then the entire line should be: 
return $($(this).data("bs.popover").tip).css({maxWidth: "300px"})

Answer (score 5):

You can use attribute data-container="body" within popover

```html
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover"
   data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" title="Title"
   data-content="Your content"></i>
```

Answer (score 4):

No final solution here :/ Just some thoughts how to "cleanly" solve this problem...

Updated version (jQuery 1.11 + Bootstrap 3.1.1 + class="col-xs-" instead of class="col-md-") of your original JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkrotoff/N99h7/

Now the same JSFiddle with your [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448902/changing-the-width-of-bootstrap-popover/19604395#19604395): http://jsfiddle.net/tkrotoff/N99h7/8/
It does not work: the popover is positioned relative to the `<div class="col-*">` + imagine you have multiple inputs for the same `<div class="col-*">`...

So if we want to keep the popover on the inputs (semantically better):

- `.popover { position: fixed; }`: but then each time you scroll the page, the popover will not follow the scroll
- `.popover { width: 100%; }`: not that good since you still depend on the parent width (i.e `<div class="col-*">`
- `.popover-content { white-space: nowrap; }`: good only if the text inside the popover is shorter than `max-width`

See http://jsfiddle.net/tkrotoff/N99h7/11/

Maybe, using very recent browsers, the [new CSS width values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) can solve the problem, I didn't try.

Answer (score 4):

`container: 'body'` normally does the trick (see JustAnil's answer above), but there's a problem if your popover is in a modal. The `z-index` places it *behind* the modal when the popover's attached to `body`. This seems to be related to [BS2 issue 5014](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5014), but I'm getting it on 3.1.1. You're not meant to use a `container` of `body`, but if you fix the code to

```
   $('#fubar').popover({
   trigger : 'hover',
   html    : true,
   dataContainer : '.modal-body',
   ...etc });
```

then you fix the `z-index` problem, but the popover width is still wrong.

The only fix I can find is to use `container: 'body'` and to add some extra css:

```
.popover { 
  max-width : 400px;
  z-index   : 1060;
}
```

Note that css solutions by themselves won't work.

Comment: +1 on it being annoying when the popover appears behind the modal. I ran into this same problem with angular-ui bootstrap directive using a tooltip with `tooltip-append-to-body`, it appeared behind the modal and the modal 'grayed out' background.

Answer (score 4):

One tested solution for Bootstrap 4 beta:

```
.popover {
        min-width: 30em !important;
    }
```

Together with the jQuery statement:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      container: 'body',
      trigger: 'focus',
      html: true,
      placement: 'top'
    })
```

Side-note, `data-container="body"` or `container: "body"` in either HTML or as an `option` to the `popover({})` object didn't really do the trick [maybe the do work but only together with the CSS statement];

Also, remember that Bootstrap 4 beta relies on [popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) for its popover and tooltip positioning (prior to that it was tether.js)

Answer (score 2):

you can also add the data-container="body" which should do the job :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" 
               data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover"
               data-container="body"
               data-content="My popover content.My popover content.My popover content.My popover content." />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow... answers the original question as well.  Clean and doesn't override bootstrap.

Comment: how does that change the width of the popover?

Comment: @t.durden I m not sure how it works, but it does exacly what the popover should do.
The author of the question had the same problem like me, the popover did not use its configured max-with, it was much smaller. And `data-container` fixes this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the width of the popover with methods indicated above, but the best thing to do is to define the width of the content before Bootstrap sees is and does its math.  For instance, I had a table, I defined it's width, then bootstrap built a popover to suit it.  (Sometimes Bootstrap has trouble determining the width, and you need to step in and hold its hand)

Answer (score 2):

I used this(working fine) :

```
.popover{
   background-color:#b94a48;
   border:none;
   border-radius:unset;
   min-width:100px;
   width:100%;
   max-width:400px;
   overflow-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <label id="txtLbl">Overview</label> <a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="popover"  data-placement="right" id="Pops" ></a>  
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
  <div class="popovermenu">
        Your content                   
  </div>
 </div>
```

I end up by setting div "popover-content" width to the number I want. (other ids 
 or class won't work.....) Good luck!

```
  #popover-content{
      width: 600px;

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution for **Bootstrap 5+** when I wanted to change the width of a specific popover. Adding a `customClass` worked for me:

Html:

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"  id="popover-help" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-content="Right popover">
   <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
</button>

<div id="popover-help-container" style="display: none;">
    <h4 style="text-align: left;"> How to:</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec condimentum ultricies elit, mattis egestas nisl suscipit ac. Duis ipsum augue, convallis sed nunc in, pellentesque luctus elit. Duis porttitor massa sed finibus rutrum. Nunc eu risus ultrices, volutpat leo eget, pulvinar eros. Donec rhoncus mattis sem, ac iaculis turpis semper non. Cras dapibus tristique risus, eu tincidunt elit condimentum fermentum. Nunc at dignissim ante, nec efficitur felis. Duis mauris magna, fermentum eu egestas vel, vehicula at est. Nullam dapibus nisi non purus pellentesque ultrices. Nulla pulvinar neque quis ipsum semper, a congue tortor aliquet. Suspendisse vulputate porttitor feugiat. Maecenas pretium porta mauris feugiat pellentesque. Integer tempus risus eu pretium consectetur.

Donec interdum, eros ac imperdiet pretium, magna risus laoreet tellus, in finibus justo sapien et lacus. Pellentesque placerat ligula at metus sollicitudin, et convallis nisi luctus. Vivamus non arcu vel ex pharetra auctor. Morbi efficitur sed turpis id finibus. Sed porttitor luctus quam sed laoreet. Nunc facilisis finibus aliquet. Maecenas pellentesque sem dui, sed blandit tortor placerat ut. Donec tempor ipsum in sem fermentum, vel vulputate magna egestas.</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id="popover-help"]'))
    var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl,{
        content: function() {
                return $('#popover-help-container').html();
            },
        html: true,
        placement: 'bottom',
        sanitize: false,
        customClass: 'popover-large'
        });
    })
</script>
```

css:

```css
.popover-large {
  max-width: 50%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
}
```

Comment: I wish this had worked but in my experience any `customClass` specified is ignored -- I checked the generated html content -- and I needed to use the `template` option and put the custom class in there instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the template of your popover. Either with the `data-template`-attribute or with the relevant part in the function that sets it up:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="text-green" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-template="<div class=&quot;popover fade top in&quot; style=&quot;max-width:none;&quot; role=&quot;tooltip&quot;><div class=&quot;arrow&quot;></div><h3 class=&quot;popover-title&quot;></h3><div class=&quot;popover-content&quot;></div></div>" data-trigger="manual" data-original-title="Some Title" data-content="<div>Some really long text and stuff. Some really long text and stuff. Some really long text and stuff. Some really long text and stuff.</div>" data-html="true" onclick="$(this).popover('show');">clickme</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

On Bootstrap 4, you can easily review the template option, by overriding the max-width :

```
$('#myButton').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'click',
    template: '<div class="popover" style="max-width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header"></h3><div class="popover-body"></div></div>'
});
```

This is a good solution if you have several popovers on page.

Comment: adding style="max-width: 500px;" didn't work for me unless I also set "sanitize" : false in the options.

Answer (score 1):

```
::ng-deep .popover{
    max-width: 600px !important; 
}
```

this works well for me "Angular 14"

Answer (score 0):

For a typescript component:

```
@Component({
    selector: "your-component",
    templateUrl: "your-template.component.html",
    styles: [`
        :host >>> .popover {
          max-width: 100%;
        }
    `]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular `ng-bootstrap` you can simply `container="body"` to the control that triggers popover (such as button or textbox). Then in your global styleing file (`style.css` or `style.scss`) file you must add `.popover { max-width: 100% !important; }`. After that, the content of the popover will automatically set to its content width.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4 you can simply override default value of bootstrap variable `$popover-max-width` in your styles.scss file like so:

```
$popover-max-width: 300px;

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/popover";
```

More on overriding bootstrap 4 defaults https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var popover_size=($('.popover').css('width'));
var string=(popover_size).split('px');
alert("string"+string);
popover_size = ((parseInt(string[0])+350));
alert("ps"+popover_size);
$('.popover').css('width',parseInt(popover_size));
```

Comment: This will not work because of the last line. Parsing an integer as value for the width will cause CSS to break. Instead you shoul try: ```$('.popover').css('width', popover_size + 'px');``` Since the popover_size is parsed as integer.

Another thing is that: ```popover_size = ((parseInt(string[0])+350));``` Will add extra width.