# the usage of parameter container in bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-popover

in most cases I found on internet, the `container` was set to `'body'`

What I encountered:

bootstrap popover shows on a fixed div content, when you scroll page, popover moves too.

I change the param container to my specific DIV `#search-filter-container`, nothing changed.

UPDATE:

what now `.popover` DIV appears within body at last even I set `container: '#some-my-div'`

```
  <div class="popover fade right in" style="top: 429.5px; left: 680px; display: block;">
    code details...
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you are interested in situations where `container` parameters may be helpful, check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448902/changing-the-width-of-bootstrap-popover

Answer (score 15):

It's hard to know what you're asking, especially because you didn't provide any code examples. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

However, to show you an example of container option usage, I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7KL4/).

Comment out each line of javascript to see the different effects (scroll up and down in the **result frame**). Don't forget to press **Run** when you change the code.

## HTML

```
<div style="height: 100px;">
    <br />Static text.</div>
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%;" id="fixed-div">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." id="popover">Popover</button>
</div>
<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>
```

## Javascript

```
// comment this
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container: "body"});

// uncomment this
//$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container: "#fixed-div"});
```

Comment: hi,sorry for unclearly asking.yes,the usage of `container` is correct as what i thought before.but within my project i took over last week, the param `container` wasn't working, the popover DIV still appears at last line of body tag.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific and include code if you want a solution to a problem. No one can help you with *"wasn't working"*.

Comment: sorry again.my english is not good.I had update my question,please check it out. thanks.

Comment: Seems like a good question to me.  "What is the purpose of this poorly documented framework"

Answer (score 5):

Use a CSS selector in the container attribute.

When the selected container scrolls, the popover will scroll too, for instance use the opener button as container, or an element near it

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-container="#popover-button" data-toggle="popover" ... id="popover-button">Open popover</button>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#popover-button').popover({container: "#popover-button"});
```