# how to size a bootstrap 2.3.2 popver

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am trying to insert a webpage's html into a bootstrap 2.3.2 popover using the following:

```
 $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url: "Ajax/getHtml",
   data: { u : 'http://stackoverflow.com' },
   dataType: 'html',    
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log('error');
     console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
   }
 }).done(function(html) {
   html = html.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
   $link = $('<a href="myreference.html" class="p1" data-html="true" data-bind="popover">');
   $link.data('content', html);
   $(this).html($link);
   // Trigger the popover to open
   $link = $(this).find('a');
   $link.popover("show");
});
```

This works fine but i want to size the output down to lets say 500 x 500 pixels. I checked out:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers
```

But do not see a sizing option. How can I do this?

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448902/changing-the-width-of-bootstrap-popover

Comment: I'll take a look, but this appears to refer to bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use popover (option "template") from Bootstrap3 http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Just a select popovers from JavaScript components and download it (like a jQuery plugins) http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `max-width`and `max-height` properties to limit the width and height of the popover. I have provided an example of how to achieve this here: http://jsfiddle.net/z96svdbe/. To avoid having the content overflow the popover, you can set the CSS `overflow-y` property to `auto`.

The following CSS will restrict the popover to 300 x 300 pixels.

```
  .max-width-popover + .popover {
        max-width: 300px;
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow-y: auto;
  }
```