# Prevent page resize from keyboard in Android Browser

Tags: javascript, html, android-browser

I am using a textbox inside a popover, but the problem is that the keyboard shrinks the size of the textbox and the user cannot see what he is entering. But in the landscape mode a separate text input field is opened on it's own by the browser where the user can enter the data, so questions:

1. is there any way that I can create a keyboard overlay so it doesn't resize the popover ?
2. Can I make that other text area to take the input when the user clicks on this textbox for every time ?

Comment: You can't prevent that event. Browser application make resize on whole document(body). Make it work with one text box in middle of screen (always 40% top - position absolute) with overlay then write function and pass arg which textField is edited. After editing hide middle textbox and overlay div and set text value for passed arg textbox html object.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to fix the height of the popover

```
.popover{
height:100px;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448902/changing-the-width-of-bootstrap-popover) is a similar page.