# How to change the width of bootstrap popover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I Have a column whose dimensions are

`width:30px` and `height:25px`

The column bears only one button if the popover is triggered, It's width scales to the width of column ... Can someone know how to increase the width of the popover?

`width:100px` and `height:50`

I have used the following css code

```
.popover{
    widht:100px;
    height:50px;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a working example please?

Comment: sorry but i don't have !

Comment: i can try to make it a bit simple my column dimension are widht:30px height:25px. so my popover dimension are also gona be the same (widht:30px height:25px). but i want to change the dimension to width:100px; height:50px;

Comment: Then change the size of your column.

Comment: i cannot change the design

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the width of Bootstrap popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448902/changing-the-width-of-bootstrap-popover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the container that is used with the popover.

This can be done via through Javsascript where you initialize the container of the popover on your specified element.

```
// where 'body' is the container you want to contain the popover within
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
container: 'body' });
```

Answer (score 8):

A solution I tested on the Bootstrap 4 Beta version:

```
.popover {
        min-width: 30em !important;
}
```