# Angular - Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a page designed in angular bootstrap. I am trying to use a popover as follws ..

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
    <ul>
    <a href="" uib-popover-template="'popOverEditTemplate.html'" popover-popup-close-delay='500' popover-placement="bottom-left"> AM TEST AM </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The template I am using pops over fine, but I could not increase the size of the popover whatsoever.

How can I increase the size of the popover?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How can I increase the size of the popover ?

Comment: I am sorry if you can't see my code snippet  ..
<ul>
      <a href="" uib-popover-template="'popOverEditTemplate.html'" popover-popup-close-delay='500' popover-placement="bottom-left"> AM TEST AM </a>
     </ul>

Comment: this fiddle may help you please check with it http://fiddle.jshell.net/J7nDz/5/light/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using CSS

```
<style>
  .popover{ /* Will change ALL popovers. Add element id to target specific popver */
    max-width: 100%
  }
</style>
```

Comment: <style>
 .popover-content {
  width: 200px;
 }
</style>
<a id="popover-content" ..
I did this and the pop over window does't change its width but the contents in it comes out of the popover window.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3x4yD/ 
You can see the effect of increasing the width (it only increases the content with in it, not the actual content window).

Comment: I think the problem is that the popover is dependent on the parent container. Adding `.popover{
  max-width: 100%
}` should solve this. You can read more about this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448902/changing-the-width-of-bootstrap-popover