# Change width of one bsPopover in Shiny

Tags: shiny, shinybs

I've just started using R-Shiny. But I have some of troubles using js and html code in Shiny.

In my app I have two `bsButton` which when hover show some text with `bsPopover`. One of these popover contains an image which is larger than the standard box of the popover and I'd like to set the width of this popover that fully contains the figure.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722672/increase-width-of-popify-pop-up-from-shinybs-in-shiny) I found how to set the width and height of all popovers, but how can I set the width/height of only a specific popover?

This is my code so far and I'd like to change the width of `bsPopover(id="q2", ...)` but not the width of `bsPopover(id="q1", ...)`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    # this changes the size of the popovers
    tags$style(".popover{width:200px;height:250px;}")
  ),

  fluidRow(
    fileInput("file", label=h4("Upload Data",
                                 tags$style(type = "text/css", "#q1 {vertical-align: top;}"),
                                 bsButton("q1", label="", icon=icon("question"), style="info", size="extra-small")), 
              accept=".txt"
    ),             

    bsPopover(id="q1", title="Title help text1",
      content=paste("help text"),
      placement = "right", 
      trigger = "hover", 
      options = list(container = "body")
    ),

    numericInput("numIn", label = h4("Choose a value",
                                    tags$style(type="text/css", "#q2 {vertical-align: top;}"),
                                    bsButton("q2", label="", icon=icon("question"), style="info", size="extra-small")),
                 value = 2.5, step=0.5),

    bsPopover(id="q2", title="Title help text 2",
      content=paste0("The figure below shows",
                     img(src='scenarios.png', align = "center", height="320px", width="800px", style="display:block;margin-top:20px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;")

      ),
      placement = "right", 
      trigger = "hover", 
      options = list(container = "body")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to solve the same issue, although using `tipify()` and `popify()` from the same `shinyBS` package. I found it really hard as it seems that dimensions of a tooltip or a pop-up are defined by the outer `<div>` container that tooltip or pop-up belongs to. Hence requires manipulation with `CSS` to resolve.

I found `tippy::tippy()` helpful here, where one could define the desired width of a tooltip inside a function, e.g.:

```
library(tippy)
tippy(
  text = "Show tooltip over this text",
  tooltip = "My tooltip text",
  width = "200px"
)
```

The `text` argument requires character string as an input. That could be your button title/text.

I used `tippy` to show a tooltip over an information icon, that required minor CSS tweaking:

`text = "<i class='fas fa-info-circle'></i>"`

Answer (score -1):

Just replace

```
tags$style(".popover{width:200px;height:250px;}")
```

with

```
tags$style("#q2{width:200px;height:250px;}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortnately this This changes the size of the button

Comment: but not the size of the popover box.